# Angle with diagonal in quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral with angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,\delta$ Is it possible to express $\angle ACB$ Using $\angle BDC$?

Comment: You mean it is possible to construct two quadrilaterals with the same angles and an angle  to diagonal with different angles with the other diagonal?

Comment: @razivo yes. Think about squares and rectangles.

Comment: @dxiv if the angels are "organized" (order maintained) than you get a family of "similar" quadrilateral. Based on the fact that he uses letters I assume the order of the angels is not related to the given angels. We know the sum of angels. There are three possible types of quadrilaterals. Will further investigate - suggest using GeoGebra.

Comment: @razivo Actually those five angles are enough to define the quadrilateral down to a similarity (for a given order of the vertices). Previous comment removed, outline of the solution posted as an answer, instead.

Comment: @moti Right, thanks. I misread the question the first time around.

Comment: Your very brief problem statement lacks important context, even assuming $\alpha$ is the interior angle at $A$ etc.  Please edit the body of your Question to share context such as where you found the problem, what research you did, or why the problem is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\angle ACB = \varphi$ and $\angle BDC = \chi$, then by the law of sines:$\;\;$[image]

$$
\begin{matrix}
\triangle ABC \text{ :} & & & & \dfrac{AB}{\sin (\varphi)} &= &\dfrac{BC}{\sin (\beta+\varphi)}
\\ \triangle BCD \text{ :} & & & & \dfrac{BC}{\sin (\chi)} &= &\dfrac{BD}{\sin (\gamma)}
\\ \triangle ABD \text{ :} & & & & \dfrac{BD}{\sin(\alpha)} &= &\dfrac{AB}{\sin(\delta - \chi)}
\end{matrix}
$$

Multiplying the three equalities has the side lengths cancel out, then $\,\cot(\varphi)\,$ can be isolated and expressed in terms of $\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\chi\,$.

Comment: does it really have to be so complicated? using trigonometry?

Comment: @razivo Most problems that are not (and do not reduce to) angle chasing will usually end up involving some trigonometry.